# how to add cl to cygwin with include path etc included

Tags: path, cygwin, include-path

For my school project, we were asked to use a makefile.microsoft with `cygwin` to compile our file etc.

But when I did that, `cygwin` complains saying that `cl` command is not found. I've tried many ways but when I am settle with cl command, it says that no `include` path set.

I've no idea what it was complaining about, and hope someone could tell me a way to deal with it once and for all.

(ps. I have both `microsoft visual studio v10` and `11` installed, so I should have all the stuff needed to `compile` but apparently its not helping =( )

Answer (score 0):

The Makefile tells Cygwin to use the MSVC command-line compiler on the sources, but that -- `cl.exe` -- is not included in the PATH by default. Several other environment variables necessary for correct operation also have to be set.

You have two options:

1) In the start menu, under "Microsoft Visual Studio  \ Visual Studio Tools", you will find several entries along the lines of "Visual Studio Command Line". Pick the one you want, and it will open a DOS box with the environment appropriately set.

2) Visual Studio provides a batch file, `<Path_to_MSVS>\VC\vcvarsall.bat`. You call it with the desired target platform as parameter, e.g. `VC\vcvarsall.bat amd64`, and it sets the environment appropriately. Use the environment variable `VS100COMNTOOLS` (for Visual Studio 10, adjust number accordingly if using another version) to find that batch file. Note, however, that in **Unix** shells, a called script cannot set variables of the calling environment. Personally, I have my bash scripts set up a `.bat` file with the call to `vcvarsall.bat` and the to-be-executed command (in your case this would be `make`), and then execute that `.bat` through `cmd /c <batchfile>`.